# Run Job in sequence in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

```
stages:
- stage: A
     jobs:
     - job: A1
     pool: CloneX
     displayname: My Job A
     - job: A2
     pool: CloneX
     displayname: My Job B
```

This is my yaml for Azure Devops.

I noticed 2 Agents( as windows service) running on same Pool machine CloneX.  Its an inhouse machine.

Job A1 and Job A2 MUST run in sequence.

However both A1 and A2 gets scheduled in parallel.

How to fix this issue?

By moving Job A2 to Stage B? OR

Keeping only 1 agent on pool CloneX?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can specify [job dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#dependencies)

```
jobs:
- job: Debug
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from the Debug build
- job: Release
  dependsOn: Debug
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from the Release build
```